# how to get results from Yahoo Ireland or Yahoo India search, using YQL

Tags: yql

I just want to use YQL to get the top 10 results for a particular query, and a region, eg Yahoo India, or Yahoo Ireland.

How do i do this?

Thanks,
Arvind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `region` value when querying against the `search.web` table, like

```
select * from search.web where query="pizza" and region="in"
```

<sup>([*Try this query the YQL console.*](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20search.web%20where%20query%3D%22pizza%22%20and%20region%3D%22in%22))</sup>

Available `region` values are listed in the [*Supported Regions and Languages for Web and News Search*](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/supp_regions_lang.html) page for the Yahoo! BOSS API, which the `search.web` data table uses.

Comment: Your example failed: No definition found for Table search.web

Comment: @Skizz that's right. See http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/yql-search-web/1311503441000-4baba010-f4ff-3935-8321-2c7204c536d8 and http://www.ysearchblog.com/2011/06/30/you-asked-for-this-boss-v2-updates/ — sadly, we can't rely on data tables being around forever.

Answer (score -1):

Following changes with the Yahoo Pipes V2 'upgrade' some YQL tables have been dropped.

Thankfully some new ones have appeared but are not widely known about yet.

```
SELECT * FROM microsoft.bing.web WHERE query="pizza india"
```